# Do what you want with specific lines from file in perl

Tags: perl

I want to do the sum of two hex files and output it in a 3rd file,the problem is I don't need to do the sum of all the file because I got text in it also.

Here's an example:

File 1:

```
There is a text here./0102030f.....**.**...Another text example./0102030f.....**.**...Excellent text example./.....
```

File 2:

```
There is a text here./020a0201.....**.**...Another text example./0102030f.....**.**...Excellent text example./.....
```

Output:

```
There is a text here./030c0510.....**.**...Another text example./0102030f.....**.**...Excellent text example./.....
```

My question is, how can you tell the program that I want it to do the sum from `./` to "the 4th dot before `Another text example./`" and forward to "again the 4th dot before `Excellent text example./`"

The code I have is something like this:

```
 use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14;
use autodie;

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', '1.txt';
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'hex1.txt';
    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;
}

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', '2.txt';
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'hex2.txt';
    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;
}
{
    open my $fh1, '<', 'hex1.txt';
    open my $fh2, '<', 'hex2.txt';

    until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {

        my @l1 = map hex, split //, <$fh1>;
        my @l2 = map hex, split //, <$fh2>;

        my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

        my @sum = map {
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
            $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
        } 0 .. $n - 1;

        @sum = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } @sum;

        open my $out, '>', 'hexsum.txt';
        print {$out} @sum, "\n";
    }
    close $fh1;
    close $fh2;
}

{

open my $IN, "<", 'hexsum.txt';
open my $OUT, ">", 'hexsumspace.txt';
        while (my $linie = <$IN>) {
    $linie =~ s/40/20/g;
    print $OUT $linie;
}
close $IN;
close $OUT;
}

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', 'hexsumspace.txt';
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'sym.txt';
    print $out pack 'H*', $input;
}
```

I don't know if I should modify in the `until` sequence or you can do this with the `split`.
Edit:
Let me make myself even more clear . File1 and File2 look like the examples above,my program will convert these 2 files into hes values,but as I said I do not want to sum all the hex values in the files,I want to sum only specific parts of the file from "./" to "the 4th dot before 'Another text example./' " and again from "the ./ until the 4th dot before 'Excellent text example' ". The output sum will be converted back into readable text.I did most of the above I just do not have any idea how to tell the program which parts of the file to work on...

Comment: Nope, sorry, you're going to have to expand on your question. Can you give a sample input and a desired output?

Comment: Actually there is sample in put and output, but it's a bit unclear. You are talking about _hex_, but the files you show just have a bunch of text, or rather you show them in character representation. Are the texts always the same, or are they of variable length? Are the dots placeholders for when there is no text there, and everything is fixed length and stuff has a fixed place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is a text here./0102030f.....**.**...Another text
                      ^              ^
                      |              |
                   from ./    to   4th dot before Another text
```

From the first file, that section would be:

```
0102030f.....**.
```

And from the second file, that section would be:

```
020a0201.....**.
```

What do you want the result of:

```
      0102030f.....**.
   +  020a0201.....**.
     ----------------
```

to be?  Do you understand why someone who sat down to take a math test might be puzzled when presented with that problem?

Secondly, do you realize that your problem would be exactly the same if each string in your file was a total of 15 or so characters long?  For instance:

```
abc/.FFdefA0jklB1
```

Thirdly, the problem is different if the strings are different lengths.  Are they?

Comment: @Sickofthisschool, What's  a *2 bit* number?  What's the result of adding periods and asterisks together?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the values that you want, convert them to decimal numbers and then do the arithmetic. You're not very clear in what output you want, but this will get you closer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  # Assumption: Every hex number is preceded by a '/'
  my @hex = m|/([0-9a-f]+)|g;

  if (@hex == 2) {
    my $sum = hex($hex[0]) + hex($hex[1]);
    say "sum is $sum (or 0x" . sprintf('%x', $sum) . ' in hex)';
  }
}
__END__
There is a text here./0102030f.....**.**...Another text example./0102030f.....**.**...Excellent text example./.....
There is a text here./020a0201.....**.**...Another text example./0102030f.....**.**...Excellent text example./..... 
There is a text here./030c0510.....**.**...Another text example./0102030f.....**.**...Excellent text example./.....
```